# How to take screenshots in Android 2.3.3 without root?

Tags: android, screenshot

I've been waiting for this feature.

Android 2.3.3 allows to take screenshot without root.

http://mobiputing.com/2011/03/google-android-2-3-3-adds-native-screenshot-support-may-break-google-voice/

Can you programmatically take screenshot? If so how?

Or is it only manually (like Home + Power button) like Apple?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reports are incorrect. The screenshot feature requires a permission that only system applications (apps signed with the system image's key) can be granted. It will not let you take a screenshot programmatically or using the phone's keys.

Comment: @romain-guy , How about grant that permission to user app or provide system screenshot app?

Comment: So all these reports rumoring around are actually incorrect? Knowing who you are(Romain Guy), your answer should be more accurate. I am very disappointed to hear that.

Comment: What is exactly the correct way to do it? I want to do it on my own rom (custom-made prototype device)

Comment: It's worth noting that [Android 4.0 allows users](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0-highlights.html#UserFeatures) to take screenshots using hardware buttons.

Comment: @Romain Guy - I need this access for enterprise solution. Is there a way I can get my app signed with the System image's keys?