# Screen shot app for Google Nexus S

Tags: android, nexus-s

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to take screenshots in Android 2.3.3 without root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161544/how-to-take-screenshots-in-android-2-3-3-without-root)

Is there any app or default functionality to take screen shot in **Google Nexus S(2.3.3) without rooting.**

I am already aware of taking screen shot using DDMS /SDK.

Comment: This question belongs in [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com), and not here.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any app or default functionality to take screen shot in Google Nexus S(2.3.3) without rooting.

No, sorry.